# How to render a specific audio unit in a AUGraph

Tags: cocoa, core-audio

I setup an AUGraph which contains several audio unit.

I know that when I call `AUGraphStart()` the graph starts the rendering of all the audio unit. But I would like to be able to start the rendering of one specific AUFilePlayer.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I saw in comment that my question lacked of details.
I have the current setup for my AUGraph:

AUFilePlayer -> AUMixer -> AUOutput

I setup the AUFilePlayer with a specific AudioFileID.

When I start the graph I would like just to "start" the graph without having any sound.
And later I would like to do something like: AUFilePlayer.Play() to start making sounds.

I don't know if it's possible...

**UPDATE: workaround found**

I think I found a workaround for this. See my answer for my details.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without knowing what you are trying to do.  The answer is technically yes, but it's a pain.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Audio Unit rendering uses the pull model.  To where do you want to render (pull) the output of your one specific audio unit?  /dev/null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following workaround:

When I setup my AUFilePlayer I set the value `mFramesToPlay` of the `ScheduledAudioFileRegion` struct to:

```
ScheduledAudioFileRegion audio_file_region;
/*... init values...*/
audio_file_region_.mFramesToPlay = 0;
```

instead of

```
audio_file_region_.mFramesToPlay = number_of_frames_for_the_audio_file;
```

That way when I start the graph, the AUFilePlayer doesn't play any sound.

Then I have a methods `Play()` where I set the right frames to play for the `mFramesToPlay` field.

I don't know if it's a good way to do this but it does its job.